# Unable to pass post variables in http request from Electron to Yii API

Tags: electron, http-post, yii2-api

I want to make API (Get & Post) requests to an API build with Yii2 using Electron.
I have tried Axion, Fetch, HTTP, request modules and all of them gave me the same error:

> data: {
> name: 'PHP Notice',
> message: 'Undefined index: username',
> code: 8,
> type: 'yii\base\ErrorException',
> file: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\ApiController.php',
> line: 898,
> 'stack-trace': [Array]
> }

Here is the code for the action I want to call:

```
public function actionLogin(){
  if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $username = $data['username'];
    $password = $data['password'];
    $device_token = $data['device_token'];
    $prefix = substr($username, 0, 3);
    $model = null;
    }
}
```

And here is the code in Electron:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/app/api/login', {
    username: 'Fred',
    psssword: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

For some reason, the parameters are not passing to the action.
I have tried a lot of ways and this one seems to be the simplest.
P.S. all of the way I have tried gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue, the way it worked was:

```
const login = async(username, password)=>{
      const data = new URLSearchParams();
      data.append('username', username);
      data.append('password', password);
      data.append('device_token', 'null');

      await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/app/api/login`,{
              method: 'post',
              body: data
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.status){
              ipcRenderer.send('user:login', data.data.user_type, data.data.access_token);
            }
            else{
              document.querySelector('#message').innerText = 'Wrong password or username';
              document.querySelector('#message').style.display = 'block';
            }

        })
    }
```